# HttpClient BlazorWASM

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor-webassembly

I Have a BlazorWASM single page app, in this app I get some data from different API servers, these API populate some tables.

- Injected client in Razor Component:

```
@inject HttpClient Http
```

The remote external API is called by the API of the app, that's no problem.

Example:

```
var x = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<APIStatus?>($"api/ExternalStatus/{ExternalId}");
/// process x...
```

But I need to call some local API that will visible only in client scope.

Example:
`http://localhost:8085`, or `http://mylocalserverapi.mydomain.local:8091`,
I think it will not work to call some internal url like this:

```
//This url is local
string url = "http://192.168.1.40:3812";
var x = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<LocalApiStatus?>(url + $"/summary");
```

I think need to config some in cors and or another stuff to get it work, also I saw the cors are in the Server Project, not Client project. This confuse me.

Can anyone help me to clarify how to do it?

Please note that local APIs can be: `http://` or `https://` with invalid certificate or `https://` with valid certificate.

Even if you share code that works in development mode, do you think it will work in production? (example: CORS configuration in allow all mode)

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Http client that got injected is already connected to your host. You cannot use it to talk to a different server

A new HTTP client has to be created for the new server

```
  var cl = new HttpClient {
        BaseAddress = new Uri("http://192.168.1.40:3812") 
   };

   var x = await cl.GetFromJsonAsync<LocalApiStatus?>("/summary");
```

Comment: Thank you @pm100, this solves partially my issue. I misunderstood `HTTPClient` class, I thought it was like an instance of a browser, not something tied to a particular Uri.
To get it work partially I also needed to configure a CA trust it, and create the certs to these api servers. But now I get an error: "typeerror: failed to fetch" I think is by Cors policy but how can I set HttpClient to permit these sites? Thank you!

Comment: @acmesoft CORS is a browser thing, not an HTTPClient thing. Investigate why you are getting that error, dont just guess